# How to compile Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 LESS using Asp.net MVC 5 and Web Essentials 2013

Tags: less, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, web-essentials

I've set up **Visual Studio 2013 RC** and **Web Essentials 2013**. I'm trying to create an Azure Cloud Service and a Web Role using **ASP.Net MVC 5**. Installed **Twitter Bootstrap Less Source 3.0** and wanted to *bundle* all *less* files using Web Essentials 2013.

I did not get any help or documentation on how to go about bundling bootstrap.less at run time or compile it into a bootstrap.css at design time.

Any idea how it can be done? Is there any simpler way than [BundleTransformer.Less](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Less).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use BundleTransformer.Less? Can't get much simpler than that.

Comment: I tried BundleTransformer by following all the steps mentioned in the documentation, but the application throws error (500 internal server error). I tried lot of debugging but could not pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I think that [BundleTransformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/) would be the best choice at this point. Whatever relies on [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) it's not going to work with the new version of LESS, which means that [Bootstrap 3.0.0](http://getbootstrap.com/) and mostly any other framework that rely on the latest LESS will not be compiled.

Comment: Also see: advanced customization of the Twitter Bootstrap library in Visual Studio: http://tarkus.me/post/70489442659

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### UPDATE (29-SEP-2015):

Leave Web Essentials and use LESS Compiler along with its Clean CSS Plugin.

1. Download and install [**Node.js**](http://nodejs.org/download/) (32-bit) for Windows.
2. Open node.js command prompt.
3. Install [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/) using the command: **npm install -g less**
4. Install [**less-plugin-clean-css**](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css) using the command: **npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css**
5. Go to *Project Properties > Build Events* and copy-paste below command to *Pre-build event command line* box:
   **lessc "$(ProjectDir)Content\bootstrap\bootstrap.less" "$(ProjectDir)Content\bootstrap.css" --clean-css="--s1 --advanced"**
6. Build the project and look for *bootstrap.css* at the specified location. (If not already, you may need to enable “Show All Files” settings in the Solution Explorer.)
7. Include the bootstrap.css file into your project. View file properties and set its “Build Action” to “Content”. Update BundleConfig to include this compiled file into your StyleBundle.
8. Select all .less files from *\Content\bootstrap* folder. View file properties and set its “Build Action” to “None”.

---

UPDATE (24-SEP-2014):

Since Twitter Boostrap has switched from RECESS to Grunt, I would recommend the new users looking for this solution to consider:
[LESS Compiler](http://lesscss.org/) or [Grunt](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt).

*Please note that **none** of the solutions mentioned here use Web Essentials 2013.*

---

Finally, I decided to use RECESS recommended by Twitter. If you want to use pre-built bootstrap 3 less into css using Visual Studio 2013 (RC / RTM), you can follow the steps given below:

1. Download and install [**Node.js**](http://nodejs.org/download/) (32-bit) for Windows.
2. Install RECESS npm package globally – Open node.js command prompt and run the command:
   **npm install recess –g**
3. Use NuGet Library Package Manager and install the [**Bootstrap Less Source 3.0.0**](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.Less/) package to your Asp.Net MVC 5 Web / Azure Web Role project.
4. Go to *Project Properties > Build Events* and copy-paste below command to *Pre-build event command line:* box:
   **recess "$(ProjectDir)Content\bootstrap\bootstrap.less" --compress > "$(ProjectDir)Content\bootstrap-compiled.css"**
5. Build the project and look for *bootstrap-compiled.css* at the specified location. (If not already, you may need to enable “Show All Files” settings in the Solution Explorer.)
6. Include the bootstrap-compiled.css file into your project. View file properties and set its “Build Action” to “Content”. Update BundleConfig to include this compiled file into your StyleBundle.
7. Select all .less files from *\Content\bootstrap* folder. View file properties and set its “Build Action” to “None”.

Comment: Thanks - brilliant. A small point to add - you might want to disable the "Generate CSS file on save" and "Minify generated CSS files on save" within Tools/Options/Web Essentials/Less.

Comment: Version 3.1 of Bootstrap has switched from Recess to grunt-contrib-less. As Visual Studio WebEssentials uses grunt for Less, I've switched to using that.

Comment: You might need to right the "-g" manually instead of coping it from here. It's > npm install recess "-g"

Comment: @SteveS: Web Essentials does not use Grunt.  (it invokes `lessc` directly)

Comment: Following the above steps produced an error for me. I needed to also add the path to recess into my PATH environment variable. After that it works great! Thanks. set path=%path%;%APPDATA%\npm;%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\nodejs

Answer (score 8):

Is possible to use '[lessc](http://lesscss.org/usage/)' command with same approach
sample:

```
   lessc "$(ProjectDir)Content\bootstrap\bootstrap.less"  "$(ProjectDir)Content\bootstrap-compiled.css"
```

Comment: For people just coming on, this seems like the best practice approach going forward.