# FontAwesome 4 LESS and Bootstrap 3 LESS bundling issue in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: less, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, asp.net-mvc-5

Created ASP.Net MVC 5 web project and installed *Twitter.Bootstrap.Less 3.0.1* and *FontAwesome.less 4.0.3* NuGet Packages.

Changed Content/fontawesome/variables.less to use
**@fa-font-path: "fonts";**

Changed Content/bootstrap/variables.less to use
**@icon-font-path:          "fonts/";

@icon-font-name:          "fontawesome-webfont";**

Changed Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less to replace glyphicons import to
**@import "../fontawesome/font-awesome";**

Compiled LESS source into bootstrap.css at build-time using RECESS. For more details, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045334/how-to-compile-twitter-bootstrap-3-0-less-using-asp-net-mvc-5-and-web-essentials/19153786#19153786).

All this works great in debug mode. But fontawesome icons do not appear in release mode i.e. when debug attribute is *removed* from web.config or when *BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;* is added in the BundleConfig.cs.

Icons are shown as square box in Chrome and blank space in IE 10.

Any idea what may be missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Solution]** Changed the virtual path of the style bundle to use **"~/Content/css"** instead of "~/bundles/css" and the problem got fixed.

The bundle path "~/bundles/css" is supposed to be *virtual* and should not exist on the file system. It is used as a *name* and not as a *path* to a physical file. If this path exists on the file system, the bundle will not get loaded. I could see all the unicode characters were missing from the compiled bootstrp.css.

This is not mentioned in any documentation which is weird!