# How to use bootstrap less through Nuget package manager in Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials Update 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, less, nuget-package, web-essentials

*As I don't have the ability to comment on a previous post and my answer therefor was deleted. A whole new thread just for the following question:*

When you install bootstrap less through visual studio 2013's Nuget package manager, it seems all the files are all in fact placed into the Content folder, however in a subfolder called bootstrap.
Out of the box, using web essentials update 2, this will not work on the existing bootstrap files which are in the main content folder.

Therefor, what is the best practice?
1) Move all the files out of the bootstrap folder and straight into the main content folder?
2) In in the bundles.config file, change the rooting to the bootstrap files to where it was installed.

I assume 2, because that way the package manager can update the folder whenever updates are available, or doesn't it work that way?

Comment: I was in similar problem until got an answer for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587216/using-grunt-grunt-contrib-less-for-compiling-bootstrap-3-1-less-in-visual-studi